# Image.FromStream( MemoryStream object )

Tags: c#

```
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data))
{
 System.Drawing.Image imgPhoto = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mem);
}
```

This is the code that I am using . The problem is that as soon as that debugger processes this line :

```
System.Drawing.Image imgPhoto = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mem);
```

It gives an error parameter invalid . So after I checked the parameters for "mem"
while it is debugging , I noticed that the position parameter is setting to zero every time .

I noticed one more thing here : 
when I am receiving images from sources beginning with url : external.xx.fbcdnsafe ... The position parameter is not setting to some value and always setting to zero and that's the time when I am getting the error . Please refer the screen shot .

But for images beginning with URL : scontent.xx.fbcdn.n...
The position parameter is setting some value . Please refer the screenshot .

[For external Sources : url starting with external.xx.fbcdn.net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjCER.jpg) 
  [For scontent Sources : url starting with scontent.xx.fbcdn.net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXTzo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You receive a "parameter invalid" exception when the format of the stream is not recognizable as an image. See

["Parameter not valid" exception loading System.Drawing.Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629955/parameter-not-valid-exception-loading-system-drawing-image)

Check the contents of the data you are receiving from your scontent.xx.fbcdn.n...  URLs. Perhaps they are a 404 error, or some other content, rather than valid image data.

Comment: Thanks ... I guess the images from external.xx.fbcdn are not valid images or the format is incorrect so this may create a problem in parsing that image ...